# Probability of $8$ boys and $7$ girls

Tags: probability

There are $15$ total children, $8$ boys and $7$ girls. $4$ are selected to organize a dance. Find the probability that:

a. All $4$ selected are boys

b. All $4$ selected are girls

c. $3$ boys and $1$ girl are selected

d. $3$ girls and $1$ boy are selected

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. You should know that this is not a homework site; you are much more likely to get help here, and useful help, if you show that you've put in some effort. That way people who answer can focus their answers on the part of the question that confuses you.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  In particular, for an exercise such as this, you should include your attempt and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Let's count the number of elements in the sample space. In total there are $|S| = \binom{15}{4}$ ways to choose a set of $4$ children from a set of $15$ distinguishable children.

## a

The event space of selecting a set of $4$ boys from $8$ distinguishable boys is:

$$|E_a| = \binom{8}{4}$$

The corresponding probability is $P_a = \frac{|E_a|}{|S|}$.

## b

The event space of selecting a set of $4$ girls from $7$ distinguishable girls is:

$$|E_b| = \binom{7}{4}$$

## c

The event space of selecting a set of $3$ boys and $1$ girl is

$$|E_c| = \binom{8}{3} \binom{7}{1}$$

## d

The event space of selecting a set of $3$ girls and $1$ boy is

$$|E_d| = \binom{8}{1} \binom{7}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a 'hypergeometric' distribution. You have a population with 7 girls and 8 boys; your select 4 at random without replacement. Let $X$ be the number of girls chosen. Possible values are 0 through 4. You can get the probability of each possible value by using combinatorial arguments as in @oxcaff's Answer (+1). [To get *probabilities,* each of the parts of that Answer need to be
divided by ${15 \choose 4}.$ For example: in (a), $P(X = 0) = \frac{{8 \choose 4}{7 \choose 0}}{{15\choose 4}} = 0.05128205.]$

It happens that hypergeometric distributions are programmed into R statistical
software, so we can make a distribution table for this particular problem (ignore numbers in brackets):

```
k = 0:4;  pdf = dhyper(k, 7, 8, 4)
cbind(k, pdf)
      k        pdf
 [1,] 0 0.05128205   # (a)
 [2,] 1 0.28717949   # (c)
 [3,] 2 0.43076923
 [4,] 3 0.20512821   # (d)
 [5,] 4 0.02564103   # (b)
```

Here is a bar graph of the PDF (or PMF) of this distribution.
This distribution is somewhat similar to $\mathsf{Binom}(4, 7/15),$
which would be the correct model if children were chosen *with* replacement.
Centers of red circles show the binomial probabilities. [The two distributions
have the same mean, but the variance of the hypergeometric distribution is
a little smaller.]

[image]